# How to store conditions to database?

Tags: database

Is there anyway to store conditions in relational databases? The condition is something like target profiling (like Facebook ads).

For example, we Facebook need to save the conditions for users who are `women` in `18 - 40 years old` and `"living in New York, US` or `Tokyo, Japan`

Thank you.

Comment: SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE (SEX = 'F') AND (LOCATION = 'NEW YORK' OR LOCATION = 'US' OR LOCATION = 'TOKYO') AND (AGE > 18 AND AGE < 40)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a table to store groups, and the group criteria? For instance, a group can be named 25-30, and we would have 2 columns a AgeFrom, and AgeTo... You would then use dynamic SQL to execute a created query on a result set - and your customers would fall automatically in the categories which are pre-configured.

Comment: Thank you. I think I found something called Rule Engine which may be what I need. Will do more researching.

Comment: You might not want to go into that complexity, but yes using a rule engine such as https://rulesengine.codeplex.com/ is an option. This obviously depends on the amount of "conditions", and how your "conditions" are defined for your business requirement.